# sqlite search in multiple column

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, search

I have a simple database in iPad Application having couple of tables.

The UI displays the table data properly in a master-detail view controller. I want to add a search feature which will search for the given text in all the field/columns of all the tables and give the result.

One crude way is to write a select query using where clause for each columns. But I believe there will be some proper way for that.

Or is it possible to search the UITableView itself and refresh the data ?

Regards,

nirav

Comment: How you displaying datas in table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for searching in Table

```
     - (void) searchTableView {


NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

if([searchText length] == 0)

{
    [searchArr addObjectsFromArray:userArr];

}


NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (int i=0; i<[userArr count]; i++) {


    NSString *sTemp =  [[userArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];

         NSRange titleResultsRange = [[sTemp lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];


        if(titleResultsRange.location != NSNotFound && titleResultsRange.location == 0)
    { 

        [searchArr addObject:[userArr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }


}
searchArray = nil;
   }
```

Comment: This will search only single column not for all columns

Comment: But You can use this to solve right?You can't expect exact answers.Do something yourself,You will get it .happy coding